# How to stretch subreports to fit parent height?

Tags: jasper-reports

I've just started using JasperReports and I stumbled upon an issue I can't seem to find a solution for.

I have a report with a subreport to create a table with 2 columns. I need the text fields in the subreports to stretch to fit the height of the first column.

Basically this is what I got

[image]

And this is what I want (I've used a static height to achieve it)

[image]

This is the code of the report

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!-- Created with Jaspersoft Studio version 6.0.0.final using JasperReports Library version 6.0.0  -->
<!-- 2023-08-21T21:38:25 -->
<jasperReport xmlns="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/jasperreport.xsd" name="monitoringBulletinRainSensors" pageWidth="595" pageHeight="842" columnWidth="555" leftMargin="0" rightMargin="0" topMargin="0" bottomMargin="0" uuid="dc5d5b62-3121-47f6-bc9c-a0c86a6de260">
    <property name="ireport.zoom" value="1.0"/>
    <property name="ireport.x" value="0"/>
    <property name="ireport.y" value="0"/>
    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.data.defaultdataadapter" value="test"/>
    <parameter name="SUBREPORT_DIR" class="java.lang.String" isForPrompting="false">
        <defaultValueExpression><![CDATA["C:\\Users\\<user>\\JaspersoftWorkspace\\MyReports\\"]]></defaultValueExpression>
    </parameter>
    <queryString language="json">
        <![CDATA[]]>
    </queryString>
    <field name="text" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <detail>
        <band height="10" splitType="Prevent">
            <property name="local_mesure_unitheight" value="pixel"/>
            <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.height" value="px"/>
            <textField isStretchWithOverflow="true">
                <reportElement key="" stretchType="RelativeToBandHeight" x="0" y="0" width="50" height="10" uuid="17091a86-28eb-4f4b-814e-2049fc13b754">
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.height" value="px"/>
                    <property name="local_mesure_unitwidth" value="pixel"/>
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.width" value="px"/>
                </reportElement>
                <box>
                    <topPen lineWidth="0.5" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                    <leftPen lineWidth="0.5" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                    <bottomPen lineWidth="0.5" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                    <rightPen lineWidth="0.5" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                </box>
                <textElement>
                    <font size="16"/>
                </textElement>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{text}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <subreport>
                <reportElement stretchType="RelativeToTallestObject" x="50" y="0" width="100" height="10" isPrintInFirstWholeBand="true" backcolor="#FFFFFF" uuid="d8d61ef2-ee12-437a-be7d-9514dc16438d">
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.y" value="pixel"/>
                    <property name="local_mesure_unitheight" value="pixel"/>
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.height" value="px"/>
                    <property name="local_mesure_unitwidth" value="pixel"/>
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.width" value="px"/>
                </reportElement>
                <dataSourceExpression><![CDATA[((net.sf.jasperreports.engine.data.JsonDataSource)$P{REPORT_DATA_SOURCE}).subDataSource("children")]]></dataSourceExpression>
                <subreportExpression><![CDATA[$P{SUBREPORT_DIR} + "test_child.jasper"]]></subreportExpression>
            </subreport>
        </band>
    </detail>
</jasperReport>
```

And this is the code of the subreport

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!-- Created with Jaspersoft Studio version 6.0.0.final using JasperReports Library version 6.0.0  -->
<!-- 2023-08-21T21:38:06 -->
<jasperReport xmlns="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/jasperreport.xsd" name="test_child" pageWidth="595" pageHeight="842" columnWidth="595" leftMargin="0" rightMargin="0" topMargin="0" bottomMargin="0" uuid="6ee7b94c-7f06-43f8-a02a-461787c5be45">
    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.data.defaultdataadapter" value="One Empty Record"/>
    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit." value="pixel"/>
    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.pageHeight" value="pixel"/>
    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.pageWidth" value="pixel"/>
    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.topMargin" value="pixel"/>
    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.bottomMargin" value="pixel"/>
    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.leftMargin" value="pixel"/>
    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.rightMargin" value="pixel"/>
    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.columnWidth" value="pixel"/>
    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.columnSpacing" value="pixel"/>
    <queryString>
        <![CDATA[]]>
    </queryString>
    <field name="text" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <background>
        <band splitType="Stretch"/>
    </background>
    <detail>
        <band height="30" splitType="Prevent">
            <textField isStretchWithOverflow="true">
                <reportElement positionType="Float" stretchType="RelativeToBandHeight" x="0" y="0" width="160" height="30" uuid="bcfd27d0-fc93-42bd-82fb-74a8d95ed706">
                    <property name="local_mesure_unitheight" value="pixel"/>
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.height" value="px"/>
                    <property name="local_mesure_unity" value="pixel"/>
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.y" value="px"/>
                </reportElement>
                <box>
                    <topPen lineWidth="0.5" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                    <leftPen lineWidth="0.5" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                    <bottomPen lineWidth="0.5" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                    <rightPen lineWidth="0.5" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                </box>
                <textElement>
                    <font size="16"/>
                </textElement>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{text}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
        </band>
    </detail>
</jasperReport>
```

Finally this is the JSON datasource I'm using

```
{
    "text": "This is a very very very very very very very long text",
    "children": [
        {
            "text": "This is a short text"
        },
        {
            "text": "This is a short text"
        },
        {
            "text": "This is a short text"
        }
    ]
}
```

Please help me! I really am happy with ANY solution, even the crappiest as long as it works :) Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Here can use (**list** or **table**) elements. and inside that (**list** or **table**) use another (**list** or **table**).

As per you JSON structure you can do that.

**Here I mention list but you can use table also.**

1. First create a report no need to add any field or query.
2. Create a **dataset1** where you have two field **text** and **children**
3. Create **dataset2** with mention **children** in query section. their you got only one **text** text-filed which is children text data
4. Add a **list** with **dataset1**, And on that list add **text** text-field and add another **list** on right side for showing **children text** data
5. On second list use **dataset2** and on that list add children **text** text-field
6. Then select position type & Stretch Type as per your require.

**Sample Output:**
[Sample Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/25NxM.png)

**This is the code of the report**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jasperReport xmlns="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/jasperreport.xsd" name="c" pageWidth="595" pageHeight="842" columnWidth="555" leftMargin="20" rightMargin="20" topMargin="20" bottomMargin="20" uuid="c9ca78e9-09e3-4234-bcd8-8cc5941a495b">
    <subDataset name="Dataset1" uuid="6a2c5d32-30c9-4945-9ee6-c2ef7b27f2c8">
        <queryString language="json">
            <![CDATA[]]>
        </queryString>
        <field name="text" class="java.lang.String">
            <property name="net.sf.jasperreports.json.field.expression" value="text"/>
            <fieldDescription><![CDATA[text]]></fieldDescription>
        </field>
        <field name="children" class="java.lang.String">
            <property name="net.sf.jasperreports.json.field.expression" value="children"/>
            <fieldDescription><![CDATA[children]]></fieldDescription>
        </field>
    </subDataset>
    <subDataset name="Dataset2" uuid="e938c415-ac02-43c5-a218-dcfcf7d80232">
        <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.data.defaultdataadapter" value="c"/>
        <queryString language="json">
            <![CDATA[children]]>
        </queryString>
        <field name="text" class="java.lang.String">
            <property name="net.sf.jasperreports.json.field.expression" value="text"/>
            <fieldDescription><![CDATA[text]]></fieldDescription>
        </field>
    </subDataset>
    <queryString language="jsonql">
        <![CDATA[]]>
    </queryString>
    <background>
        <band splitType="Stretch"/>
    </background>
    <title>
        <band height="20" splitType="Stretch"/>
    </title>
    <pageHeader>
        <band height="21" splitType="Stretch"/>
    </pageHeader>
    <columnHeader>
        <band height="19" splitType="Stretch"/>
    </columnHeader>
    <detail>
        <band height="30" splitType="Stretch">
            <componentElement>
                <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="440" height="30" uuid="92f28b3e-ddc6-48c6-8aff-e44bf28feab0">
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.CONTENTS.height" value="px"/>
                </reportElement>
                <jr:list xmlns:jr="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports/components" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports/components http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/components.xsd" printOrder="Vertical">
                    <datasetRun subDataset="Dataset1" uuid="dd4e597b-4228-41ba-b0d0-72fdbf85a82e">
                        <dataSourceExpression><![CDATA[((net.sf.jasperreports.engine.data.JsonDataSource)$P{REPORT_DATA_SOURCE}).subDataSource()]]></dataSourceExpression>
                    </datasetRun>
                    <jr:listContents height="33" width="440">
                        <textField>
                            <reportElement stretchType="RelativeToTallestObject" x="0" y="0" width="240" height="30" uuid="ca2fbeb2-c057-4b6c-afb0-80f5e87e4530"/>
                            <box>
                                <topPen lineWidth="1.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                                <leftPen lineWidth="1.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                                <bottomPen lineWidth="1.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                                <rightPen lineWidth="1.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                            </box>
                            <textElement verticalAlignment="Middle"/>
                            <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{text}]]></textFieldExpression>
                        </textField>
                        <componentElement>
                            <reportElement stretchType="RelativeToTallestObject" x="240" y="0" width="200" height="30" uuid="274af469-c856-477e-8687-abcbe6008b77"/>
                            <jr:list printOrder="Vertical">
                                <datasetRun subDataset="Dataset2" uuid="512eb811-336f-401c-ac81-b08e05fa7017">
                                    <dataSourceExpression><![CDATA[((net.sf.jasperreports.engine.data.JsonDataSource)$P{REPORT_DATA_SOURCE}).subDataSource("children")]]></dataSourceExpression>
                                </datasetRun>
                                <jr:listContents height="30" width="200">
                                    <textField>
                                        <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="200" height="30" uuid="3c04f2b1-3287-4a18-afa6-b735af62000a"/>
                                        <box>
                                            <topPen lineWidth="1.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                                            <leftPen lineWidth="1.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                                            <bottomPen lineWidth="1.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                                            <rightPen lineWidth="1.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                                        </box>
                                        <textElement verticalAlignment="Middle"/>
                                        <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{text}]]></textFieldExpression>
                                    </textField>
                                </jr:listContents>
                            </jr:list>
                        </componentElement>
                    </jr:listContents>
                </jr:list>
            </componentElement>
        </band>
    </detail>
    <columnFooter>
        <band height="17" splitType="Stretch"/>
    </columnFooter>
    <pageFooter>
        <band height="22" splitType="Stretch"/>
    </pageFooter>
    <summary>
        <band height="14" splitType="Stretch"/>
    </summary>
</jasperReport>
```

**Finally this is the JSON datasource I'm using**

```
[{
    "text": "This is a very very very very very very very long text",
    "children": [
        {
            "text": "This is a short text"
        },
        {
            "text": "This is a short text"
        },
        {
            "text": "This is a short text"
        }
    ]
},
{
    "text": "This is a Second very very very very very very very long text",
    "children": [
        {
            "text": "This is a second short text"
        },
        {
            "text": "This is a second short text"
        },
        {
            "text": "This is a second short text"
        }
    ]
}]
```